# Extracting an unknown string between two known strings

Tags: c#, string, console-application, substring, indexof

I have the following string:

```
string nextEvent = "[[\"nextData\", \"RANDOM MESSAGE\"], [\"moreInfo\", {\"num\": 3204}]]"
```

I need to get "RANDOM MESSAGE" (without the quotes) into a seperate string. Now, it would be easy if RANDOM MESSAGE was a constant, but it's not. Let's say that it's generated through user input, and is different in value and length every time.

How would I go about extracting that message from there? I've tried using Substring with IndexOf, but I got wrong results every time, it's quite confusing.

Comment: Can the rest of the string change?

Comment: In `"[[\"nextData\"", \"" + message + "[\"moreInfo\", {\"num\": "`, message is the only thing that will change.

Comment: this looks like a JSON-Dictionary. you could go for parsing it to a `Dictionary<string, object> dict = JSON.Parse<Dictionary<string,object>>(nextEvent)` and then extract it by: `dict("nextData")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get it:

```
string input = "[[\\\"nextData\\\", \\\"RANDOM MESSAGE\\\"], [\\\"moreInfo\\\", {\\\"num\\\": 3204}]]";
string pattern = "^\\[\\[\\\\\"nextData\\\\\",\\s*\\\\\"(?<message>[\\S ]+)\\\\\"\\],\\s*\\[\\\\\"moreInfo\\\\\",\\s*\\{\\\\\"num\\\\\":\\s*\\d+\\}\\]\\]$";
Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = r1.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["message"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a 'brute force' method:

```
String nextEvent = "[[\"nextData\", \"RANDOM MESSAGE\"], [\"moreInfo\", {\"num\": 3204}]]";
String tmp = nextEvent.Trim(new Char[] { '[', ']' });
String[] sa = tmp.Split(',');
String rndMsg = sa[1].Trim().Trim(new Char[] { '[', ']', '\"' });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple splits like this:

```
  string nextEvent = "[[\"nextData\", \"RANDOM MESSAGE\"], [\"moreInfo\", {\"num\": 3204}]]";
  var strs = nextEvent.Split(']');
  var ds = strs[0].Split(',');
  var m = ds[1].TrimStart('"', ' ');
  m = m.TrimEnd('"');
```

Answer (score 0):

The third possible solution, although not very performing is this:

Take you string and parse it as a Dictionary:

```cs
String nextEvent="[[\"nextData\",\"RANDOM MESSAGE\"],[\"moreInfo\",{\"num:\": 3204}]]";
Dictionary<string, object> dict =  JSON.Parse<Dictionary<string,object>>(nextEvent);
String randomMessage = dict("nextData");
```

this becomes relevant, when you have a very long string in this format and have to extract multiple "fields" from it

Answer (score 0):

If the strings before/after are constant you can get the random message part simply by doing:

```
int startIndex = ("[[\"nextData\", \"").Length; 
int endIndex = nextEvent.IndexOf(", [\"moreInfo\""); 
string randomMessage = nextEvent.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex );
```

You might also use `Split` to get a string starting from the target area:

```
string[] temp = nextEvent.Split(new string[] { "[[\"nextData\", \"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//temp[1] = "RANDOM MESSAGE..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {            
       string nextEvent = "[[\"nextData\", \"RANDOM MESSAGE\"], [\"moreInfo\", {\"num\": 3204}]]";
       JObject json = JObject.Parse("{\"j\":" + nextEvent + "}");
       string randomMessage = (string)json["j"][0][1]; 
       Console.WriteLine(randomMessage); // gives "RANDOM MESSAGE"
    }
}
```